Blazor execute code for a specific route pattern
0
I have a set of pages that all follow a similar pattern of /{report}/{id} but where {report} is replaced with a concrete name for each page. We also have a singleton reportManager that used to be updated in the page's OnParameterSet
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
   if (reportManager.SelectedId != id) {
       reportManager.SelectedId = id;
   }

   var item = reportManager.SelectedItem;
}

Instead of having to remember to put this on every new page is there a way to have this run for all the report pages
I have tried creating a component to wrap the pages, but since it i a component on the page, its OnParameterSet runs after the page's, so when the page loads reportManager.SelectedItem is not correctly set.
I have also thought about just creating a page for all the pages:
@page "/{reportName}/{id}"

<div>
@switch reportName {
   case "report1": 
      <Report1 />
      break;
   case "report2":
      <Report2 />
      break;
   ...
}
</div>

@ {
[Parameter]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string ReportName { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
   if (reportManager.SelectedId != id) {
       reportManager.SelectedId = id;
   }

   var item = reportManager.SelectedItem;
}
}

But then this just requires that every time someone needs to remember to add the page here. Is there any way to just run this code for a set of paths?

You can implement this requirement by using custom ReportPageBase. Then use it in your razor component like @inherits ReportPageBase.
